# iOS 9 UIStackView setting others UIStackView height 0

Tags: ios9, uistackview

`UIStackView` setting others `UIStackView` height 0 and setting `ImageView` size bigger and covering whole screen. I am following this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O0llR7sfrkc). How to resolve this issue, please help me. I am beginner to iOS. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Clip to bounds property for `ImageView`.

[image]